# How to get maintenance interval from maintenance outcomes?

Tags: predictive-modeling, regression, distribution

I have a machine, which needs maintenance.

Every time the technician visits the machine, there are four possible outcomes: 
a) The machine is broken, b) The machine is still running, but it's high time that maintenance is performed, c) It's now the right time for maintenance: Something should be done, but it's not too late d) The technician came too early, there's nothing to do at this moment.

The technician rates every visit to the machine, and the goal is that the rating is c) every time. I want to write a software which helps determine the perfect maintenance interval *I* to achieve that.

I would model it like p(a)+p(b)+p(c)+p(d) = 1; with the probability distribution of p depending on *I*. I'd expect that p(a) increases with *I*, while p(d) decreases. If I had a good approximation to p(*I*), I could determine the next maintenance time when p(c) has the maximal likelihood.

However, I am new to Machine Learning and don't really know how I could get a reasonable function for p(*I*).

How can I determine p(*I*) from a number of observations? Any hints where I could starting reading into the topic?

Answer (score 0):

One way to frame the problem is multi-class classification. Given a collection of features, predict one of four mutually exclusive outcomes.

As far as modeling goes, it makes sense to simplify the modeling process to ignore time. This is similar to the bag-of-words assumption in natural language processing (NLP) which ignores word order. You can build a model the predicts one of four outcomes based on the current state of the machine.

Later, you can try a more complex modeling process like time series or survival analysis.